# Access wordpress blog on subdirectory /blog that is running on subdomain

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, proxy, wordpress

I have my main site https://mysite.com in nextjs and wordpress blog on subdomain https://blog.mysite.com. They both are hosted on different servers and diff hostings.

I need my blog to be accessible via subdirectory in main site - https://mysite.com/blog

I have successfully proxied nextjs https://mysite.com/blog to see blog but blog's internal links, pages, posts, media is still pointing to subdomain.

```
async rewrites() {
return [
  {
    source: '/blog',
    destination: 'https://blog.mysite.com/',
  },
  {
    source: '/blog/:slug',
    destination: 'https://blog.mysite.com/:slug', // Matched parameters can be used in the destination
  },
]
```

},

I have tried many solutions but end up breaking wordpress config

Need help

solutions tried

- https://medium.com/one-weekend-at-a-time/how-to-reverseproxy-wordpress-at-blog-from-any-sub-domain-ec8e5159e305
- https://proxyscrape.com/blog/using-a-reverse-proxy-to-install-a-wordpress-blog-for-enhanced-seo

Comment: You will need to change a lot of things in the database itself, as WordPress does not like having such a structure changed after installation. The [WordPress SE site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be the place to get help on this.

Comment: I am ready to experiment since this is important. @matigo thanks for pointing to right forum